# c++: Expected primary-expression

Tags: c++

I have been struggling with a certain error that doesn't make sense to me. Whenever I try to compile this program, it tells me that I'm missing a semicolon when I am not.

It seems the error is linked to a specific block of code, that being the if statement that checks stock. Since I know c++ can be platform specific, I'm running debian 9 and the atom ide if that's any help.

Here is the specifc error:

> error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
>
> getline(string,line);//gets string`

and the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "store stocking system: \n"; // yadda yadda yadda UX
    cout << "commands: \n";
    cout << "  help: shows available commands\n  check stock: checks store stock\n  enter stock: enter new stock items\n";
    cout << "  exit: terminates the program\n  clean house: deletes all stock\n";
    home: // main loop in program
    string output;
    output = ">> ";
    cout << output;


    string stock;
    string item; // this whole block just defines things and gets input
    int itemNumber;
    string userInput;
    getline(cin,userInput);

    if (userInput == "exit")
    {
      return 0;
    }

    if (userInput == "enter stock")
    { // enters new stock
      cout << "enter item\n>> "; //item name
      cin >> item;
      cout << "enter amount\n>> "; //amount of item
      cin >> itemNumber;
      ofstream myfile; //makes file
      myfile.open("stock.txt"); //opens myfile
      myfile << "\n" << item << "," << itemNumber << "\n"; //writes to file
      myfile.close();// closes file
      cout << "done";
      goto home; //finishes and goes to main loop
    }

    if (userInput == "check stock") // where the problem is
    {
      string line;
      ifstream file("stock.txt");//checks fo file
      file.open("stock.txt");//opens file
      getline(string,line);//gets string
      file.close();//closes it
      cout << line << "\n";
      goto home;
    }

    if (userInput == ""){
      goto home;
    }

    else
    {
      cout << "\033[1;31mplease use a proper command:\033[0m\n";
      goto home;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `getline(file,line);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing this by any chance?

```cpp
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it simply needs to be `getline(file,line)` rather than `getline(string,line)` and then you should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is recognized as a type name, of type `std::string` which you generously exposed by line `using namespace std;`. This particular error message is caused by fact that `string` isn't an expression which can be evaluated . In context of your code it should be

```
getline(file,line);
```

PS. Standard would say that you have to include `<string>` header to use component `std::string`. Your code compiles thanks to an implementation-defined feature,  was imported with `<iostream>` in this version of header.

Comment: i tried this and it did get my code to actually run! but then it wouldnt return anything from the file after using the command.

Comment: @MontyAngel you have to check for file status, is it even open and check for EOF after reading. if the file contains only one string it have to contain end of line before the end of file, getline stops at EOL only,